# How to flattening array at javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, flatten

I have code `[ 1, 2, 3, fn(), 7, 8 ]`

The `fn` does next:

```
fn(){ return [ 5, 6 ] }
```

Which operator to apply to `fn()` call to get:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
```

instead of:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, [ 5, 6 ], 7, 8 ]
```

Of course It is possible to do:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, fn(), 7, 8 ].flat()
```

But at this case other elements will be flattened too. I need flattening **only** for `fn()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling `fn`, [*spread*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) it into the array you're creating:

```js
const fn = () => [ 5, 6 ];

const arr = [ 1, 2, 3, ...fn(), 7, 8, [9, 10]]
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) returns values of the callback function of each element of the input array as an array which is then returned flattened. For example, the callback can be made to return the following:

- **One-to-one:** return **[** *value* **]**
- **One-to-none:** return **[ ]**
- **One-to-many:** return **[** *value*, *value* -5, *arbritaryValue* **]**

In the demo if the value is an array -- it will be returned as is -- otherwise it will be returned within an array. Essentially, all values will be returned from callback as an array which in turn gets flattened.

```js
const fn = () => [5, 6];

let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, fn(), 7, 8];

const result = array.flatMap(node => Array.isArray(node) ? node : [node]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I need flattening only for `fn()`. It is not desired to `flat` second element in case it is `[2]`